# Does synchronized block prevent other threads from making insertions into a synchronized list?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

So I am working on a multithreaded java application and I had this question:

```
List<Integer> mlist = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Integer>());
public void addStuff(int a){
   mlist.add(a) // mlist is a synchronized list
}

public void traverseArray(){
   synchronized(mlist){
    // traversing mlist using normal for loop
   }

}
```

in the above code if one thread is trying to add an element to mlist using `addStuff()` will another thread be allowed to enter the synchronized block in `TraverseArray()` method?
or vice versa
if a thread is traversing the list using the synchronized block in `TraverseArray()` method , will another thread be allowed to add element to the list using `addStuff()` method?

Comment: No. `mlist` is internally synchronized on itself, so `mlist.add` is effectively surrounded by `synchronized (mlist) { ... }`.

Comment: What do you mean by _synchronized list_?

Comment: ...In other words, please extend your code example to show how the list was created. The answer below, and the comment by Andy Turner both seem to _assume_ that you created it by calling `Collections.synchronizedList(...)`, but is that really true? When you say "synchronized list," how do we know that you aren't talking about something else?

Comment: @SolomonSlow  yes I mean a List created as follows ```List<Integer> mlist = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Integer>());```

Comment: Does that answer your question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69638281/synchronize-on-list/69639245#69639245

Answer (score 2):

Synchronizing on the list is **required** by the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList-java.util.List-).

> It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned
> list when iterating over it:

```
  List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());
      ...
  synchronized (list) {
      Iterator i = list.iterator(); // Must be in synchronized block
      while (i.hasNext())
          foo(i.next());
  }
```

You can therefore infer that modifications by other threads are blocked as long as the above code is in the synchronized block.

Comment: Yes I knew that. What I didnt know was that ``.add()`` is also within a synchronized block by default. Are you saying that ```.add()``` is not within a synchronized block ?

Comment: I'm saying that the implementation requires explicit synch for iterators, and does not require explicit synch for add.  The documentation guarantees that this is safe.   (Interally we can guess the implementation syncs on itself for 'add' but we do not need to know that to use it safely, having read the documentation).