# Synchronize on List

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

Suppose I have this code block:

```
List<Integer> lst = Collections.synchronizedCollection(new ArrayList<>());
```

And I have the following two methods:

```
public Integer returnFirst() {
  lst.get(0);
}

public void iterate() {
synchronized(lst) {
     Iterator i = lst.iterator();
     while (i.hasNext()) {
       System.out.println(i);
     }
   }
}
```

Supposed that a thread calls iterate(), then another thread calls returnFirst(). Would returnFirst() be blocked since you are synchronizing on the List object in iterate, and iterate is currently running?

Comment: Does your code compile?

Comment: No. That keyword is for queueing tasks, unless `returnFirst()` is synchronized with the same **object**.

Comment: @Darkman - the lst is internally synchronized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.
Take a look at the `SynchronizedCollection` constructor amd `SynchronizedList#get` method:

```
        SynchronizedCollection(Collection<E> c) {
            this.c = Objects.requireNonNull(c);
            mutex = this;
        }
```

```
        public E get(int index) {
            synchronized (mutex) {return list.get(index);}
        }
```

You can see that the internal mutex used to control concurrent access is actually the object itself(`mutex = this`), this means that `lst.get(0)` and `synchronized(LST)` in your `iterate()` method compete for the same lock: the object itself.

In addition, your code will not compile, replace `synchronizedCollection` with `synchronizedList`.

Simple code test:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        List<Integer> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
        list.add(1);
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                synchronized(list) {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    Iterator i = list.iterator();
                    while (i.hasNext()) {
                        System.out.println(i.next());
                    }
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }).start();
        Thread.sleep(100);
        new Thread(() -> {
            // It will block for 5 seconds and then output
            System.out.println(list.get(0));
        }).start();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you're correct.  `returnFirst` won't run until `iterate` is complete.

Comment: Why would returnFirst not run though? It's not synchronized, so I would think that it's not blocked.

Comment: It **is** synchronized. `List<Integer> lst = Collections.synchronizedCollection(new ArrayList<>());`.  It is synchronized on the collection that `lst` refers to, This exact case is covered in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedCollection-java.util.Collection-),

Comment: @Mason That means `get()` is synchronized by the same object which is `lst`, either with `synchronized get()` or `synchronized(this) {}` and `lst == this`. And this is unsafe to assume that it uses the same lock -- the developvers might change that, but I doubt it.